# biblatex: combine author-year and verbose styles

Tags: biblatex

I would like to modify the **authoryear** citestyle in such a way that *the first time a citation appears, a footnote giving the complete reference is added to the citation*. The behavior would be similar to the standard **verbose** citestyle, only that, instead of creating a footnote entry for every citation, it uses the authoryear style everywhere, adding a footnote only the first time a citation appears -ideally in the chapter-.

I would like something like the following:

> [...] as described by Sagan (1997)^1. Indeed, Sagan (1997) and Schulze-Makuch and Irwin (2004)^2 perfectly describe the feeling that we are trying to convey.
>
> [1] Sagan, C., (1997). Pale blue dot: A vision of the human future in space. Random House Digital, Inc.
>
> [2] Schulze-Makuch, D., & Irwin, L. N. (2004). Life in the Universe. Springer-Verlag.editions.

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the following. The macro definitions are adapted from the originals in `authoryear.cbx`. Unfortunately, some trickery is needed to get the order of brackets and footnotes right for `\textcite`. (This should work for `authoryear`, for more complex styles like `authoryear-comp` it would be much more complicated).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, citetracker, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{first:fullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\mkbibfootnote{%
       \usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
         {\thefield{entrytype}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}%
  \usebibmacro{first:fullcite}}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{textcite:first:fullcite:check}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\global\undef\cbx@fullcitekey}
    {\savefield{entrykey}{\cbx@fullcitekey}}}

\newbibmacro*{textcite:first:fullcite:print}{%
  \ifundef\cbx@fullcitekey
    {}
    {\entrydata{\cbx@fullcitekey}{%
       \mkbibfootnote{%
         \usedriver
           {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
           {\thefield{entrytype}}}}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{%
       \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
       \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{citeyear}}%
  \usebibmacro{textcite:first:fullcite:check}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite:postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibcloseparen}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{textcite:first:fullcite:print}}
    {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{postnotedelim}}}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{extpostnotedelim}\bibopenparen}}%
     \printfield{postnote}\bibcloseparen
     \usebibmacro{textcite:first:fullcite:print}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
      \usebibmacro{textcite:first:fullcite:print}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \textcite{nussbaum}
dolor \textcite{sigfridsson}
sit \textcite{worman}
amet \textcite{geer,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations with footnotes]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your solution seems to work quite well. I need to do a couple more tests, but so far it behaves as I expected. Thanks again.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly well. Would you have any tip though as to how to deal with running out of space in the margin? I am using a wide margin for the footnotes, and thus, when too many new citations appear in a page, some of them are lost out of the page. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @ManueldelJesus Mhh yes, space in margins is an issue. You could try to make the citations more compact by removing certain bits of the data in the footnotes (`\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}\clearlist{publisher}}` or some such).

Comment: Just to add more information, the package `marginfix` seems to solve the issue with margin space, at least for now.